# Move Query (Criteria-API) between EntityManagers

Tags: java, sql, spring, criteria-api

I have a criteria created from one `EntityManager`.

```
final CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
final CriteriaQuery query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery();
```

I store that criteria in a RestController.

Now I like to execute the query in a Singleton-Service but I get a Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Session/EntityManager is closed
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.checkOpen(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:326)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.SharedSessionContractImplementor.checkOpen(SharedSessionContractImplementor.java:126)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getPersistenceContext(SessionImpl.java:2234)
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.isReadOnly(AbstractProducedQuery.java:238)
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getQueryParameters(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1249)
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1404)
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1374)
at org.hibernate.Query.getResultList(Query.java:417)
at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:55)
```

How to *merge* the query to the new EntityManager?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than moving an object that you've created with one `EntityManager` into the context of another one, why not just create the object lazily? So, instead of doing:

```
final CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
final CriteriaQuery query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery();
```

Do this instead:

```
Function<EntityManager, CriteriaQuery> function = em -> {
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery();
    ...
    return query;
}
```

The lazily constructed query will always be constructed in the right context.

Comment: @PeterRader: Have you actually measured this? A lot of people wrestle with these caching issues based purely on unverified assumptions. If you did measure this, have you considered just resorting to plain SQL (stored in a String) and then running a native query?

Comment: @PeterRader: Would be *very interesting* to see the benchmarks then! I'm not aware of such problems, but I'd be very interesting to learn about them. Do you blog?